# Can't get .htaccess to work on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get mod_rewrite to work by using a .htaccess file on my localhost server.

My apache2.conf file contains:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And:

```
Include mods-enabled/*.load
```

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load file contains:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

The .so file exists.

`service apache2 restart` shows no warnings/errors

My .htaccess contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /process.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

And it's located at `/var/www/wp/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/`

process.php contains `print_r($_SERVER);`

I am visiting http://localhost/wp/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/randomstring and always getting a 404 error.

I tried changing the .htaccess file to a random string trying to trigger a 500 error to make sure the .htaccess was being "executed"(?), but still getting a 404 not found error.

`var_dump(in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules()));` returns true

what am i doing wrong? This always works on my online servers.

Comment: Have you tried 'sudo a2enmod rewrite' ?

Comment: check phpinfo() is rewrite module enabled

Comment: @Nikhil it returns: `ERROR: Module rewrite not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load is a real file, not touching it` how should i proceed? phpinfo() shows mod_rewrite in loaded modules.

Comment: Check this: http://xmodulo.com/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-apache2-on-debian-ubuntu.html

Comment: @Nikhil Thanks a lot. I had to edit the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file and change all the AllowOverride from none to All. If you can put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Added answer. Glad to know that it's got working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the module is enabled using php_info(). If there is some errors.

Try the following command.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

I think if you change (/etc/apache2/sites-available/default) `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All` then it will work.

If still you are getting the error, then do the steps mentioned [here](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-apache2-on-debian-ubuntu.html).

The tutorial is bit old, but you can get the module working.

I hope this helps.