# Enable .htaccess in ubuntu server for php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I have my files in ubuntu server. I have a .htaccess file in my project. And i am not able to access that file in the server. I want to enable .htaccess files in my server. How to do?

This is my code in my /var/www/html/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you have ssh access?

Comment: Yes I have ssh access

Comment: You want to edit the htaccess file or enable mod_rewrite? If you want enable mod_rewrite run this command: "sudo a2enmod rewrite" and then reload the apache server. To edit htaccess navigate to your website root and run "ls -la" now you can see the .htaccess file, "vi .htaccess" to edit the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable .htaccess (mod_rewrite)

Login to SSH and do follwing,

```
john@doe:~$  sudo a2enmod rewrite
john@doe:~$  sudo service apache2 reload
```

Usually this is how the rewrite module is enabled in Ubuntu.

To view and edit hidden files via terminal.

```
john@doe:~$  cd /var/www/html/your_website_root/
john@doe:~$  ls -la # this command will display all files including hidden files.
john@doe:~$  vi .htaccess # to edit the htaccess file
```

You can use vi, vim and nano etc.. for editing files via terminal.

If still the htaccess not working, do following change in the virtual host entry.

Change

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

To

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I could edit and add in .htacess. But its not working

Comment: @varuni Have you tried to enable mod rewrite module?

Comment: I tried the same you have told me. I edited and added the code. Still not working

Comment: Is there a 500 error message when opening the website?

Comment: If no, make an error in the htaccess purposefully. And see if there is a 500 error. If there is an error which means the rewrite_module/htaccess is working properly (revert the file if there is errors). check Apache error log and see if there is any errors.

Comment: Only index.php files are running

Comment: For other files its saying not found i.e. 404 error

Comment: Are you trying this in your local machine?

Comment: No online. I have my files uploaded to the server. So online only index.php files are working

Comment: Please check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348548/cant-get-htaccess-to-work-on-localhost/34348750#34348750

Comment: Strange :-( one last thing "tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log" run this command in terminal and open the website (you can see real time error messages in terminal).

Comment: AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/html/beta/404 (None could be negotiated).

Comment: Not sure, check this article: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2218-negotiation-discovered-file-s-matching-request-none-could-be-negotiated.htm

BTW your website is hosted in a sub-folder called /beta?  or is it just a website path?

Comment: Thank you very much bennadel.com/blog this worked for me :)

Comment: HI there,

I am running .htaccess on the folder where i started my server through php -S localhost:8080, is it correct or do I need to actually enable additional settings?